# Is $a=b$ the only possibility?

Tags: functions

> In the following: $$2a-2b+(b^2-a^2)\operatorname{sinh} (by)\cos(ax)=0, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R},$$ does it result automatically that $a=b$ in order for this to hold?

Is there any other possibility? Why?

Comment: What does $$sh$$ mean?

Comment: hyperbolic sine. Should I change it to sinh? I've been using both notations

Comment: I think most readers would find $\sinh$ self-explanatory.  Personally, I've never seen it written $sh.$

Comment: It was the notation  when I was a student. And also ch, th, coth.

Comment: No, it's the parameter b multiplied with y

Comment: @Bernard  May I ask where you studied?

Comment: it's the argument of sinh :))) sorry, i'm really bad at formatting

Comment: @saulspatz: Paris (France).

Comment: @saulspatz well, in Romania we also have tg instead of tan. And arctg instead of arctan, etc

Comment: Yes, tg is also used for tangent in Spanish.

Comment: Anyway if $a\ne b$ divide both sides by $a-b$ and you'll get a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say $a\ne b$ then we have $$2-(b+a)\sinh(by)\cos(ax)=0$$ for each $x,y$. So for $y=0$ we get $2=0$.

A contradiction.